# Measure similarity between 2 vectors

Tags: java, math, vector, similarity

I'm trying to calculate the similarity between 2 sentences, so I have 2 set of words, each represents a sentence, and a function (F) that receives two words and return the similarity between them in a way ..
[image: Image 1]

In Image 1, the black circles are the words of sentence A, and the red squares represent sentence B.
For each time function (F) receives 2 words, it returns a value between 0.0 and 1.0, for example: the first word in A and the third of B have 0.3 similarity score.
I have used M x N comparison because the order of the two sentences often not the same, and also number of words.

My questions are:

1. After getting all M x N comparison scores, how could i get a final
   score between 0.0 and 1.0 that denotes the similarity of the two
   sentences or lists? "**since the length of the two sentences is not always
   equal**".
2. If this approach is not right, what's the alternative?

Comment: Interesting.  How did you define similar?

Comment: I don't think it's clear exactly what you are trying to do. Do you have a matrix of similarity scores? I'm not sure what M x N comparison is supposed to mean. Is the question pertaining to some "similarity" topic or mathematics? Maybe people lacking experience in "similarity" can still provide assistance.

Comment: @NickZiebert , semantically using shortest path in an Ontology.

Comment: How "similar" would you define two sentences with the same words in reverse order?

Comment: @Marshalcraft , "I don't think it's clear exactly what you are trying to do" are you sure ? my question is very simply ..

Comment: What are some examples? what two words would give you a 1, a 0, and 0.5?

Comment: @NickZiebert , if they are Synonym and have the same Father in a tree, so the path between them is 0 , this is WUP model.

Comment: @AJNeufeld , the similarity in meaning for the whole sentence .. i'm sure about my idea, it's a part of a project.

Comment: What's the issue with just averaging the 8 numbers?

Comment: Then it should be no problem for you to spell out the M x N comparison a little more, yes?

Comment: "I like cooking my family and my pets" and "I like cooking, my family and my pets" are very similar.  They use the same words, in the same order.  But they mean so very different things.

Comment: @NickZiebert , not true, since if we have 2 long sentences, and they are the same, the comparison process will give 1 for N x M pairs that are the same and zero for others, the large number of zeros will decrease the average but they are same.

Comment: @marshalcraft, i meant by M x N comparison , that each word in A vector will be compared with each word in B vector.

Comment: @MIB Minion how to understand  `semantically using shortest path in an Ontology`， and what is ` WUP model`, can you give some relevant links ? I am making a research about *similarity* base on **VSM** and I am very interesting with your method.

Comment: @AJNeufeld, i didn't goes deeply in my question, there are more details, i have before separate between verbs nouns etc., so i know what you are talking about ..

Comment: @cainiaofei, check the following link: http://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2004/AAAI04-160.pdf

Comment: I think you should apply the algorithm you did above.  Then, pick the path with highest similarity, and remove the word pair from A and B.  Repeat this process until all words from A are gone.  Finally, take average of these numbers. So  the above would give (1+0.8)/2=0.9 similarity.

Comment: Interesting.  If you are parsing grammar, your sentence might have a subject, a verb and an object.  The subject would have nouns, or pronouns (or both with conjunctions), which could have adjectives.  The verb could have adverbs. The object would be similar to the subject (nouns, adjectives, etc).  I think you want a tree of words, not a vector!  Similarity based on tree structure, so the same words, used differently, would not be compared.

Comment: Yeah, there is a big difference between comparing two groups of words, and two sentences.

Comment: @AJNeufeld , i know what you are talking about, our project has other dimensions .. thanks for your explanation ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the score for the above chart in the following way:

1- When I get 2 lists, the shorter one will be on the left side.

2- for each word on the left side, I have extracted the max (1.0 in our example) then divide it by the number of the words on the right side to get a score for the word.

3- finally, I have summed up the scores for the words to get the final score then divide it by the number of the words on the left.
(1 + 0.8)/2 = 0.4

This type of calculation depends on the nature of the relations since each word could has relations above of ZERO, but if each word has just one relation above of ZERO with the other relations we shouldn't divide the final scores by the number of the words in the final step.